# IPython.display.Markdown does not render KaTeX correctly

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, markdown, katex

When trying to display a mathematical equation, it seems as if KaTeX only considers the first letter following a `\` when rendering the equation. Here is an example:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
display(md("$ \frac{1}{2}) $"))

ParseError: KaTeX parse error: Unexpected character: '' at position 1: ̲rac{1}{2})
```

I'm using Python 3.9 in VS Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting an `r` before your string. Your string will be considered a so called raw string and the backslash will not escape the f character.

This should work

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
display(md(r"$ \frac{1}{2}) $"))
```

The backslash is used to form so-called [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) when used together with another character. In your case it seems like KaTeX had trouble to interpret the \f (or 'form feed') character.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to solve it! I had the same trouble using `\left(` and `\right)`, and ultimately wanted to combine this syntax with f-strings (e.g. `f"$ \left( {a} \right)  $"`). However, the `r` modifier works with the `f` modifier, and `rf"$ \left( {a} \right)  $"` gives the expected behaviour. Thanks again!